# Creating events in Google Calendar (100 Days of Google Dev) Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm following the youtube tutorial on Creating events in [Google Calendar (100 Days of Google Dev)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNo9IoZMelI&feature=youtu.be&index=97&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJDPXCTt5TLDu67271PruEk) just to try it out and get it up and running.

I've copied the python code and have this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
CAL = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

GMT_OFF = '00:00'      # PDT/MST/GMT-7
EVENT = {
    'summary': 'Dinner with friends',
    'start':  {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T19:00:00%s' % GMT_OFF},
    'end':    {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T22:00:00%s' % GMT_OFF},
    'attendees': [
        {'email': 'friend1@example.com'},
        {'email': 'friend2@example.com'},
    ],
}

e = CAL.events().insert(calendarId='primary',
        sendNotifications=True, body=EVENT).execute()

print('''*** %r event added:
    Start: %s
    End:   %s''' % (e['summary'].encode('utf-8'),
        e['start']['dateTime'], e['end']['dateTime']))
```

Although it works perfectly in the video, I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/henry/Documents/calendars/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access storage.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 16, in <module>
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/calendars/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/calendars/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2125, in flow_from_clientsecrets
    cache=cache)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/calendars/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/calendars/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 125, in _loadfile
    exc.strerror, exc.errno)
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

So I appear to be missing storage.json but I cannot fund anything about getting it installed or anything.  Could anyone help me please.  Thank you.

Comment: `storage.json` is a file. Try creating that file using `touch storage.json` and seeing what happens.

Comment: that removes the warning part of the error but the Traceback onwards remains unchanged

Comment: You're missing a `client_secret.json` - you probably should have downloaded one from the Google developer console.

Comment: Do I have to run the API from Google App Engine?  I cannot work out how to create/obtain/download a client_secret.json

Comment: I've worked out how to get the client_secret.json but I'm now getting a subsequent error which I've put in the EDIT

Comment: Acutally - it's working